# Using Varien_File_Csv and _prepareDownloadResponse to return csv

Tags: php, csv

I am creating csv exporter for some custom tables where multiple tables are combined in a way that is not like any model or grid in the back end. In the controller I have a action function that collects the data and combines it into a 2 dimensional array. I am currently trying to refine the function that converts the array into a string for _prepareDownloadResponse and am wondering if it can be used together with Varien_File_Csv to convert an array to a csv.

I know the following works, though some extra processing is needed around the implode.

```
$csv_data = array();

// Add data to $csv_data

$fileName = "example.csv";

$content = "";
foreach($csv_data as $line){
  $content .= implode(",", $line)."\n";
}

$this->_prepareDownloadResponse($fileName, $content);
```

I am wondering if the following is possible

```
$csv_data = array();

// Add data to $csv_data

$fileName = "example.csv";

$var_csv = new Varien_File_Csv();

$var_csv->saveData($fileName, $csv_data);

// a step here is need to get the string out of the file into $content

$this->_prepareDownloadResponse($fileName, $content);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it like that, although I do not think that it is better than your first solution:

```
$csv_data = array();

// Add data to $csv_data

$fileName = "example.csv";

$var_csv = new Varien_File_Csv();

$var_csv->saveData($fileName, $csv_data);

$this->_prepareDownloadResponse($fileName, array('type' => 'filename', 'value' => $fileName));
```

This will write the CSV data to a file (`saveData()`), will read it from there and will prepare a download response for it (`_prepareDownloadResponse`). Sine there is a file write and file read here, I think it is better to use your first code, which does not need that and which is therefore probably faster.

Comment: this is the code : https://justpaste.it/1g31g how can i download into var->export folder

Answer (score 0):

This is possible. See this [guide](http://www.creare.co.uk/using-varien_file_csv-with-magento).

Basically:

```
$file = 'example.csv';
$csv = new Varien_File_Csv();
$csvdata = array();
$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();

foreach ($products as $product)
{
    $product_data = array();
    $product_data['id'] = $product->getId();
    $product_data['sku'] = $product->getSku();

    $csvdata[] = $product_data;
}

$csv->saveData($file, $csvdata);
```

Comment: This writes the content to a CSV file, but does not provide a download response.

Comment: Yeah, i forgot to add what a way i found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15353508/how-to-download-the-files-in-magento

Answer (score 0):

As an easy approach you can create the csv file separately and then use the location of the file as URL to download the file.

```
    $file_url = file_location
    $downloadName = 'filename.csv';
    return $this->_prepareDownloadResponse($downloadName, array('type' => 'filename', 'value' => $file_url,'rm' => true));
```